# How to install a Python package inside a docker image?

Tags: python, docker

Is there a way to install a python package without rebuilding the docker image? I have tried in this way:

```
docker compose run --rm web sh -c "pip install requests"
```

but if I list the packages using

```
docker-compose run --rm web sh -c "pip freeze"
```

I don't get the new one.
It looks like that is installed in the container but not in the image.

My question is what is the best way to install a new python package after building the docker image?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you edit the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: You remove the container after every command. What do you expect to persist?

Comment: Do you mean to install packages at runtime? or you wish to update the image itself with python packages? i.e are these dependency dynamic?

Comment: @PranjalDoshi well, say for example I need the ```request``` after building the image how can install it?

Comment: Docker is usually used to package an application for deployment. It doesn't make much sense to install packages without rebuilding the image as those packages would not be part of the deployed image then.

Comment: @HansKilian I know that, but we are using also the docker during the development

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose` is used to run multi-container applications with Docker.

It seems that in your case you use Docker image with python installed as entrypoint to do some further work.

After building docker image you can run it:

`$ docker run -dit -name my_container_name image_name`

And then run:

`$ docker exec -ti my_container_name bash` or

`$ docker exec -ti my_container_name sh`

in case there is no bash in the docker image.
This will give you shell access to the container you just created. Then if there is pip installed inside your container you can install whatever python package you need like you would do on your OS.

Take note that everything you install is only persisted inside the container you created. If you delete this container, all the things you installed manually will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about docker but if you execute your commands, the docker engine will spin up a new container based on your `web` image and runs the `pip install requests` command. After it executed the command, the container has nothing more to do and will stop. Since you specified the `--rm` flag, the docker engine will remove your new container after it has stopped such that the whole container and thus also the installed packages are removed.

AFAIK you cannot add packages without rebuilding the image.
I know that you can run the command without removing the container and that you can also make images from your containers. (Those images should include the packages then).